# QuickBooks connection using asp

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, quickbooks

May not be the best place to ask sorry if that's true.
I have worked on SQL and while I never worked on QuickBooks I am hoping it is possible to connect to it and just use it similar to a SQL Database. I am wondering I am wondering if it is possible to connect to  QuickBooks using ASP. My purpose is to create simple forms and insert the data into QuickBooks similar to what is done on SQL.Occasionally I would just generate reports as well using web pages. All I am wondering is does ASP have the capability to connect to Quick Books and if so can I also run query's similar to SQL and is there any sources or reference available for research ? And what my options are for setting this up. If I have to use asp.net as a last resort that is fine too, though I would prefer to have to be without it.

Thank you

Update #1

While i am working on getting the Version of Quick-Books here is what information I have.

I plan on using ASP-Classic, and I want to develop web forms so this would be a website that can be accessed. This will not be a desktop application I plan on making but various webpage's where you can view Quick-books data, and insert records into Quick-books using forms, similar to what I do for SQL. And the Version of our Quick-Books is 2013 Enterprise Windows Desktop USA edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I am wondering is does ASP have the capability to connect to Quick Books

Yes.

> can I also run query's similar to SQL

Maybe.

QuickBooks itself does not provide an SQL-based interface. Communication with QuickBooks is via XML. However, QuickBooks Enterprise comes with something called [QODBC](http://www.qodbc.com/) which provides an ODBC interface to the XML interface QuickBooks provides, which might get you what you need.

One problem you want to watch out for -- there are times when you won't be able to connect to QuickBooks. e.g. it is not an "always-on" solution like a typical SQL database is. If you're in single-user mode in QuickBooks, or someone closes QuickBooks, or someone is doing a QuickBooks backup, or someone is updating QuickBooks, then you won't be able to connect. You'll have to plan for this in your application.

A better solution might be to use the [QuickBooks SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb) (specifically the QuickBooks Web Connector). If you download and install the SDK there is example code included. The SDK install also includes about 600 pages of PDF documentation on topics which you are asking about.

Striking out the below stuff since you've provided more details now: <strike>But unfortunately you didn't provide anywhere near enough information for anyone to actually give you a decent answer.</strike>

How about providing some actual details so that people can actually help you? Like, maybe:

- Is this QuickBooks ONLINE, or QuickBooks for WINDOWS, or QuickBooks for MAC? (they are three entirely separate products, with entirely separate sets of capabilities)
- What version/year/edition/country of QuickBooks?
- ASP classic or ASP.NET?
- Is this a website you're connecting from, or is this a desktop application, or...?

Comment: I answered 2 out of 4 so 50%, sorry i was just asked a while ago about this. So I will try to get more information on this as I relay it fast. But I want to make this a website to connect to , and fill out forms. and the language i am talking about is ASP classic.

Comment: I answered all your questions as best as i can.

Comment: Edited now that you've provided more details.

Comment: Thank you for the information. And i will definitely try my best with both the QODBC and the QBSDK. Is there any good books your recommend for this type of programming ?

Comment: The QuickBooks SDK guide is 600 pages, free, and included with the QuickBooks SDK. I'd start there.

Comment: Okay , Checking out QODBC I can see classic VBS and classic ASP on there website as examples which is nice. Does the QuickBook SDK support Classic ASP ?

Comment: Yes. If you're using the Web Connector, it will work with ANY language.